# Convert XML or HTML to entity number (not entity name) in Java

Tags: java, xml, entity

Is there an easy way to convert XML or HTML characters to their entity numbers?
I am using org.apache.commons.lang3 which has functions like these:

StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml()
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4()

However these are replacing angle brackets etc. with the entity names, not the numbers.

e.g.
StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml("<"); //Returns &lt but I need &#60

Is there a way to make these functions return &#60 instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HtmlUtils from Springsframework

```
import org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils;
[...]
HtmlUtils.htmlEscapeDecimal("&")` //gives &#38;
```

OR May be you can try this piece of code :

```
public static String escapeHTML(String s) {
StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder(Math.max(16, s.length()));
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    char c = s.charAt(i);
    if (c > 127 || c == '"' || c == '<' || c == '>' || c == '&') {
        out.append("&#");
        out.append((int) c);
        out.append(';');
    } else {
        out.append(c);
    }
}
return out.toString();
```

}